# how do I change the following macro to let me add labels or to enumerate using numbers?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I have the following macro that I found:

```
\newenvironment{itemizetight}[2]
  {\begin{list}{\labelitemi}{%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{#1}%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   }%
  }
  {\end{list}}
```

However, it does not let me use `\item[1.]`. How can I change it so that I can use labels like in a typical itemize environment? Or alternatively, what would be the parallel for an enumerate environment?

The way to use it, for example is:

```
\begin{itemizetight}{-0.2em}{0.5em}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemizetight}
```

Comment: You should look up the `enumitem` package; it would make your life easier for this sort of things.

Comment: I can't see any reason why `\item` should not work as usual (since you show no code that changes it) Please _always_ include a _complete_ document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that I'm able to use things like `\item[1.]` inside your `itemizetight` environment, the "parallel" for the `enumerate` environment could be:

```
\newenvironment{enumtight}[2]
  {\begin{list}{\labelenumi}{%
     \usecounter{enumi}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{#1}%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   }%
  }
  {\end{list}}
```

You only have to change `\labelitemi` to `\labelenumi` and add the line `\usecounter{enumi}` to let the `list` use this counter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{itemizetight}[2]
  {\begin{list}{\labelitemi}{%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{#1}%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   }%
  }
  {\end{list}}

\newenvironment{enumtight}[2]
  {\begin{list}{\labelenumi}{%
     \usecounter{enumi}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{#1}%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   }%
  }
  {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemizetight}{-0.2em}{0.5em}
\item[1.] item 1
\item[2.] item 2
\end{itemizetight}

\begin{enumtight}{-0.2em}{0.5em}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{enumtight}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]